# Are there any pros to using PCL profile 111 over 259 for Xamarin and MvvmCross?

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

I've been working on a cross-platform Xamarin app targeting iOS and Android only (no windows platform support required), using Stuart Lodge's excellent MvvmCross framework.

Microsoft released versions of their Portable Class Library BCL packages, and Stuart describes how to setup a project with these in http://slodge.blogspot.com.au/2013/11/quick-run-through-using-pcls-in.html.

I have been using profile 259 happily for a few projects, but now I need to use profile 111 for a library I must use called [refit](https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit). I need to make sure I'm not shooting myself in the foot by making this change for one library.

Why would one use profile 259 over profile 111? Vice versa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Profile111` targets `portable-net45+netcore45+wpa81`

`Profile259` targets `portable-net45+netcore45+wpa81+wp8`

The difference being that `Profile259` has support for Windows Phone Silverlight (8.0), whereas `Profile111` does not. If you don't require Windows Phone Silverlight support, you'll be fine.

Comment: Thank you!!
I thought there could be more to consider, not just what platform it supports.

Comment: Silverlight is dead, use Profile111 it makes things much easier to use and you have access to better reflection APIs

Comment: @Cheesebaron this is funny because most of the nuget packages requires us to use 259 instead of 111. I dont understand this. for example, AWSSDK, I have seen many others.